# Error al Descargar Archivos Blob de MySQL en C# Windows Form

Tags: mysql, c#, blob, filewriter, filereader

Estoy trabajando con un base de datos, que tiene ya registros antiguos guardados, quiero guardar y descargar archivos esta tabla ya existente. encontré unos métodos en internet para eso, y funciona muy bien con los archivo viejos, pero los archivos nuevos que recién guardo, después de descargarlos me sale un mensaje de que están dañados y no se pueden visualizar.

código de Guardar:

```
    private bool GuardarArchivoBloob(string ruta)
    {
        bool val = false;

        GeneralBD c = new GeneralBD();
        int idArchivo1 =Convert.ToInt32(c.SelectCount("select max(idArchivo1) id from archivo1", "id"));
        byte[] ArchivoByte = File.ReadAllBytes(@ruta);
        string cadena = "INSERT INTO archivo2(`idArchivo2`,`IdArchivo1`,`Archivo`,`Digito`) VALUES " +
            "(0,"+ idArchivo1 + ",'"+ ArchivoByte + "',1)";
        Conexion.connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(cadena, Conexion.connection);
        int flag = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Conexion.connection.Close();
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            val = true;
        }

        return val;
    }
```

Código para descargar Archivo:

```
    private void DescargarArchivo(int IdArchivo,string nombre)
    {
        try
        {
            string ruta = this.RutaGuardar + nombre + "";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string cadena = "select Archivo from archivo2 a2 inner join archivo1 a1 on a2.IdArchivo1=a1.IdArchivo1 where a1.idArchivo1=" + IdArchivo + "";
            Conexion.connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(cadena, Conexion.connection);
            MySqlDataAdapter data = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            Conexion.connection.Close();

            data.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Archivo"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                byte[] ArchivoExtraido = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Archivo"];
                File.WriteAllBytes(ruta, ArchivoExtraido);
                Process.Start(ruta);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: "+ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El archivo se guardaba mal debido, a que el archivo en Bytes lo tenia que insertar como un parametro de mysql de la siguiente forma

```
    private bool GuardarArchivoBloob(string ruta)
    {
        bool val = false;

        GeneralBD c = new GeneralBD();
        int idArchivo1 =Convert.ToInt32(c.SelectCount("select max(idArchivo1) id from archivo1", "id"));
        byte[] ArchivoByte = File.ReadAllBytes(@ruta);
        string cadena = "INSERT INTO archivo2(`idArchivo2`,`IdArchivo1`,`Archivo`,`Digito`) VALUES " +
            "(0,"+ idArchivo1 + ",@imagen,1)";
        Conexion.connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(cadena, Conexion.connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("imagen", ArchivoByte);
        int flag = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Conexion.connection.Close();
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            val = true;
        }

        return val;
    }
```